# JVM crashes with no frame specified, only "timer expired, abort"

Tags: java, hadoop, java-native-interface

I am running a Java job under Hadoop which is crashing the JVM.  I suspect this is due to some JNI code (it uses JBLAS with a multithreaded native BLAS implementation).  However, while I expect the crash log to supply the "problematic frame" for debugging, instead the log looks like:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f204dd6fb27, pid=19570, tid=139776470402816
#
# JRE version: 6.0_38-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.13-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# # [ timer expired, abort... ]
```

Does the JVM have some timer for how long it will wait when producing this crash dump output? If so, is there a way to increase the time so I can get more helpful information?  I don't think the timer referred to is coming from Hadoop, since I see (unhelpful) references to this error in many places which do not mention Hadoop.

Googling appears to show that the string "timer expired, abort" only shows up in these JVM error messages, so it is unlikely to come from the OS.

**Edit:** It looks like I am probably out of luck.  From `./hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp`
 in the OpenJDK version of the JVM source:

```
 if (is_error_reported()) {
   // A fatal error has happened, the error handler(VMError::report_and_die)
   // should abort JVM after creating an error log file. However in some
   // rare cases, the error handler itself might deadlock. Here we try to
   // kill JVM if the fatal error handler fails to abort in 2 minutes.
   //
   // This code is in WatcherThread because WatcherThread wakes up
   // periodically so the fatal error handler doesn't need to do anything;
   // also because the WatcherThread is less likely to crash than other
   // threads.

   for (;;) {
     if (!ShowMessageBoxOnError
      && (OnError == NULL || OnError[0] == '\0')
      && Arguments::abort_hook() == NULL) {
          os::sleep(this, 2 * 60 * 1000, false);
          fdStream err(defaultStream::output_fd());
          err.print_raw_cr("# [ timer expired, abort... ]");
          // skip atexit/vm_exit/vm_abort hooks
          os::die();
     }

     // Wake up 5 seconds later, the fatal handler may reset OnError or
     // ShowMessageBoxOnError when it is ready to abort.
     os::sleep(this, 5 * 1000, false);
   }
 }
```

It appears to be hard-coded to wait two minutes.  Why crash reporting for my job is taking longer than that, I don't know, but I think this question at least has been answered.

Comment: It looks like you are on Linux...did you get a core dump?

Comment: I don't think so. Certainly the log doesn't say anything about it, and I can't find one.  The job is being run under Hadoop, so I don't have the ability to do the usual shell commands to request a core dump, assuming those are necessary.

Comment: If it is only on one server, you might want to check the RAM on that machine. Otherwise you can try to get dumps by supplying the hadoop child configuration `mapred.child.java.opts` e.g. set to `-Xdump:java+heap+system+snap:events=user`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like I am probably out of luck. From ./hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp in the OpenJDK version of the JVM source:

```
 if (is_error_reported()) {
   // A fatal error has happened, the error handler(VMError::report_and_die)
   // should abort JVM after creating an error log file. However in some
   // rare cases, the error handler itself might deadlock. Here we try to
   // kill JVM if the fatal error handler fails to abort in 2 minutes.
   //
   // This code is in WatcherThread because WatcherThread wakes up
   // periodically so the fatal error handler doesn't need to do anything;
   // also because the WatcherThread is less likely to crash than other
   // threads.

   for (;;) {
     if (!ShowMessageBoxOnError
      && (OnError == NULL || OnError[0] == '\0')
      && Arguments::abort_hook() == NULL) {
          os::sleep(this, 2 * 60 * 1000, false);
          fdStream err(defaultStream::output_fd());
          err.print_raw_cr("# [ timer expired, abort... ]");
          // skip atexit/vm_exit/vm_abort hooks
          os::die();
     }

     // Wake up 5 seconds later, the fatal handler may reset OnError or
     // ShowMessageBoxOnError when it is ready to abort.
     os::sleep(this, 5 * 1000, false);
   }
 }
```

It appears to be hard-coded to wait two minutes. Why crash reporting for my job is taking longer than that, I don't know, but I think this question at least has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

The way around this is to specify `-XX:ShowMessageBoxOnError` on the command line and attach to the process with a debugger from another term.