# timer expired ...abort Jmeter ERROR(Non gui mode) - while running the Load test up to 3000 Users

Tags: jmeter

I was performing the Load test up to 3000 users on 16GB RAM and on EC2 instance. when the user reached 2000+, I got the Error ***timer expired, ...abort*** in command prompt. During this period Memory & CPU usage was up to 96%

Let me know is this error occurred due to Memory and CPU usage went up to 96% ?or anything to do with Jmeter scripts. bcoz Up to 1K it was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20477221/2897748) to the [JVM crashes with no frame specified, only “timer expired, abort”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427361/jvm-crashes-with-no-frame-specified-only-timer-expired-abort) it occurs when a fatal error has occurred and the JVM wasn't properly switched off in 2 minutes time frame.

Most probably 3000 users is way too much for your test for that VM. Moreover 96% of usage of CPU and RAM is a little bit too much for me, I would rather stop ramping up the users when CPU/RAM usage starts exceeding 80% of total available capacity.

So the next step would be:

1. Configure JMeter to ramp-up users gradually, i.e. 3000 users in 15 minutes or so
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Make sure to setup realtime monitoring of CPU, RAM and other resources
4. Start your test
5. See how many virtual users were online when resources usage starts exceeding 80% using ie. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener

If you have 3000 users - you should be good to go, if not - you will need to create another machine and to [run JMeter in Distributed Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the feedback,